# Creating one line for multiple data

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, merge, multipart, singlepart

Using QGIS, I want one line representing three data in the attribute table. I merged and used the multipart to single part. Only one data in the attribute table appears. Is it possible to get multiple data row from one line?

[image]

Comment: Can you show your data/attribute table ?

Comment: I dont understand what you are asking. Maybe it is Dissolve you need

Comment: A single feature cannot have multiple entries in the attribute table, that would be the opposite of what a single feature is.